# Is there a c++ equivalent to COLOR.whatever like java?

Tags: java, c++, colors

I'm trying to set a "color variable" in a simple game I want to write and i just want to make the background of a tile whatever color I set so I was wondering if I could use something like java's `COLOR.blue` in c++

Comment: C++ has no notion of "color" or "game". Are you talking about a specific library?

Comment: I assume he means the Color class from the Java class library: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ Look for Color

Comment: On a language level Java doesn't have any notion of color either. It's part of the awt library that is part of the standard libraries but not part of the language itself. In C++ this would depend on the gui library you use - AFAIK there isn't a standard one, since this is platform dependent. However, there are a few commonly used like QT or GTK.

Comment: im using openGL and SDL on linux i read that windows has some COLORREF thing but it seems to be windows only and that obviously wont help so i guess im asking if SDL or openGL have something like glColor.RED but that doesnt seem to work either

Comment: Color is part of Java's awt library, the abstract windowing toolkit. It's a library for creating window GUIs. What library are you using for making tiles in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better forget about color names and just use hex values intead:

```
Uint32 blue = 0x0000FF;
```

Or if you need to use alpha channel:

```
Uint32 blue = 0x880000FF; // ~50% transparent blue
```

Much easier to handle colors that way, especially if you are familiar with HTML coding.

Comment: Yeah, right, and RGBA8888 is the only color format out there.

Comment: Yeah I always found `0xffff00` much easier to understand than `yellow`.

Comment: @n0rd, most probably yeah, if youre using a palet, then you obviously dont use this method.

Comment: @Voo, are you being sarcastic? because IMO FFFF00 is much easier to understand, and easier to modify too, what if i want slightly darker yellow etc... really easy to handle the colors.

Answer (score 5):

This strongly depends on platform and framework which are you using. For example when you're using open GL, you have at lest 4 ways to store RGB/RGBA colors, those are:

```cpp
int rgb[3]; // 0-255
int rgba[4]  
float rgb[3];// 0.0f - 1.0f
float rgba[4];
```

So you will have to create your own static class which will return pointers to correct float/int sequence. When you're creating [texture](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluBuild2DMipmaps.xml) you've got even more options (see format and type).

When you're using [Windows CMD](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/code/216334) the colors will also work different and you could do:

```cpp
#define COLOR_RED 16
```

So to answer your question: No, C++ doesn't provide any way to handle colors uniformly (because many frameworks runs using C++ and each has it's own color structures), but it offers you many options how you can build easy color access by yourself (and some frameworks does provide this option, such as [Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qcolor.html#predefined-colors)).

Comment: @Cygal at first I was like <serious face> but then I LOLed. (He mark this answer as answer first, but he changed his mind). I guess this is about finding the easiest solutions for your problems, which was `Uint32 blue` (which I didn't think about at fist). In fact, OpenGL can and will accept bytes in form `Uint32` as `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` with `ARGB` color format (but still I'd go with `RGBA`, it just seem more common and usable in `glColor3dv, glColor3d, glColor4d, glColor4dv`.

Comment: @Vyktor, you mean glColor4f() ? because im not sure the doubles are preferred in OGL since its not supported on most cards, and you really dont need 64bit precision for each color component! I usually go with 32bit (ARGB) or 32*4bit ARGB float, since those two are the most efficient for GPU. on vertex arrays i use the 32bit ARGB even though its slightly less efficient than floats but it takes 4 times less memory.

Comment: @Rookie Ou, I meant `glColor3i` and so on (integer values). I mixed it up with `%d` in `printf`

Comment: @Vyktor, i think you mean glColor4ub() since you dont want to send 32bit integers for each color element.

Answer (score 0):

Qt has a QColor class and predefined colors like Qt::red.

Comment: this is similar to what im looking for but im not using the qt libs just openGL and SDL

Answer (score 0):

No (not in the standard C++ libraries anyway) but you can write one yourself.

```
enum Colour{ 
    RED,
    BLUE,
    GREEN
};
Colour myColour = RED; //Colour::RED is non-compliant with the C++ standard... which led to the discussion below.
```

Of course you could also make it complicated and build comparators for various things, split the colour and alpha channels etc... Gosh it sounds like fun! Might do it myself! :P

Comment: Are you sure it is C++ you used in the code snippet of yours?

Comment: @n0rd what's wrong with it? Looks fine to me but I haven't compiled it or anything. Just using it to illustrate the idea.

Comment: Looks like C#, certainly not like C++.

Comment: Maybe because I incorrectly used "." instead of "::". But that aside it is C++.

Comment: You can't put enum name before members in C++, though some compilers allow it.

Comment: as in Colour::RED? It's only a warning on the visual compiler. But then MS don't have the best record of compliance. I will modify the answer.